# equivalent to pointer to function as in C++ in Java

Tags: java, c++, function, pointers

Is there any equivalent to what is in C++ pointer to function in Java.
For example

```
double (*f)(double)
```

And is there any way to have a function with similar to what is pointer to function in C++, as parameter list.

Comment: @MattBall the accepted answer does contemplate Java 8

Comment: @MattBall: Can you not mark it as a duplicate? As E_net4 pointed out, there is an easy solution in Java 8 (using a functional interface).

Comment: @DaveDoknjas I don't understand. The second sentence of your comment specifically argues in favor of closing as a duplicate.

Comment: @MattBall: The existing answer referenced does not give the concise Java 8 solution (i.e., functional interface).

Comment: The 'answer' referenced has one note about Java 8 lambdas, but lambdas *do not* provide function pointer or delegate functionality - they support assigning to functional interface instances, which *do* provide function pointer or delegate functionality.